# How to deserialize nested multi-level polymorphic types

Tags: asp.net, polymorphism, deserialization

Hello i have a hierarchy of classes where at each level there is an `payload` field and an `id` field by which you can deserialize the payload.My question is how can you deserialize something like that considering you i do not want to flatten the hierarchy.

I need to take decisions at every step :

```
        public class Root
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public Message msg { get; set; }
        }
        public abstract class Message
        {
            public int MessageID { get; set; }
        }

        public abstract class Com : Message
        {
            public int ComMsgId { get; set; }
        }
        public abstract class Game : Message
        {
            public int GameMsgID { get; set; }
        }
        public class Game1 : Game
        {
            public string Data { get; set; }
        }
        public class Com1 : Com
        {
            public bool IsDone { get; set; }
        }
```

I have attached a picture for further clafirication :
[image: Hierarchy of classes]

**P.S** I have tried using  the`JsonSubTypes` library  but it does not work on multilevel of polymorphism.Is there anything else i can do ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason because there's no cleaner approach to this is because JSON doesn't holds metadata information and inferring sub classes on the basis of property names is a very complex and resource intensive approach.

I address this issue by creating a virtual property in `Message` class which indicates the type of class being deserialized and assign a value to it in each subclass. For e.g. in Com1

```
public override string ClassName => nameof(Com1)
```

Then implement a `CustomSubClassConverter` inherited by `JsonConverter` in which you override the ReadJson attribute to convert the JSON by applying switch case on ClassName property.

Then mark your `Message` class with `[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomSubClassConverter))]`

I'll be more than glad to provide you with the code of CustomSubClassConverter if you want me to.

**UPDATE**

You can also use reflection to get the subclass instead of using switch/cases if you want it to be more easily adaptable to addition of new classes

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using the `abstract` field as a `discriminator` in the attribute.This field would be defined in the `root` and be overridden only in `leaf`-s.
Then separately i would implement the discriminated union.

To be able to cast at any level in the hierarchy i would decorate the intermediary abstract classes with their respective leafs:

So for example having a class hierarchy like this:

`M`
`M1:M`,`M2:M`
[`M11:M1`,`M12:M1`] ; [`M21:M2`,`M22:M2`] 

 where the leaf's are `M11,M12,M21,M22` i have wrote the following code:

**Root**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubTypes.JsonSubtypes), propType)]
[JsonSubTypes.JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(M.M1.M11),Leaf.M11)]
[JsonSubTypes.JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(M.M1.M12), Leaf.M12)]
[JsonSubTypes.JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(M.M2.M21), Leaf.M21)]
[JsonSubTypes.JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(M.M2.M22), Leaf.M22)]
public abstract partial class M
{
    public static void Process(M message){

        switch(message.MKind){
            case M.Discriminator.M1 : M.M1.Process(message.AsM1);break;
            case M.Discriminator.M2: M.M2.Process(message.AsM2);break;
        }
    }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsM1=>this.MKind==Discriminator.M1;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsM2=>this.MKind==Discriminator.M2;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public M1 AsM1=>this as M1;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public M2 AsM2=>this as M2;
    private const string propType="$LeafKind";

    public enum Discriminator {
        M1=0,
        M2=1
    }
    public enum Leaf {
        M11=M1.Discriminator.M11*10,
        M12=M1.Discriminator.M12*10,
        M21=M2.Discriminator.M21*10,
        M22=M2.Discriminator.M22*10
    }



    [JsonProperty(propType)]
    public abstract Leaf LeafKind{get;}



    protected abstract Discriminator MKind{get;}
    public Discriminator Kind=>this.MKind;

    public DateTime timestamp { get;}
}
```

**Abstract Branch (level 2)**

```
       [JsonSubTypes.JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(M.M1.M11), 
       M.Leaf.M11)]
       [JsonSubTypes.JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(M.M1.M12),M.Leaf.M12)]
        public abstract partial class M1:M
        {
            public static   void  Process(M1 message){
                switch(message.M1Kind){
                    case M1.Discriminator.M11 : M1.M11.Process(message.AsM11);break;
                    case M1.Discriminator.M12:  M1.M12.Process(message.AsM12);break;
                }
            }
            protected override M.Discriminator MKind => M.Discriminator.M1;
            public new enum Discriminator {
                M11=10,
                M12=11
            }
            public new Discriminator Kind => this.M1Kind;

            protected abstract Discriminator M1Kind { get; }
            [JsonIgnore]
            public bool IsM11=>this.M1Kind==M1.Discriminator.M11;
            [JsonIgnore]
            public bool IsM12=>this.M1Kind==M1.Discriminator.M12;
            [JsonIgnore]
            public M11 AsM11=>this as M11;
            [JsonIgnore]
            public M12 AsM12=>this as M12;   
        }
```

**Leaf**

```
public class M11 : M1
            {
                public static void Process(M11 message){
                    Console.WriteLine(message.Value);
                }

                public bool Value{get;set;}


                protected override Discriminator M1Kind => Discriminator.M11;

                public override Leaf LeafKind => Leaf.M11;
            }
```

To be able to cast an object of type `M11` to `M1` i need to decorate `M1` with the `KnownSubTypes`, but override the `discriminator` only in the leafs.

**P.S** I have not added all the `subtypes` here but you can find the full implementation with a small sample in the [Source Code](https://github.com/sanzor/DUnion)

**Update**
I have reimplemented the hierarchy using an `enum` instead of string as `Discriminator`.